# Connecting resistors to the wires directly decreases the audio output

Tags: audio, resistance, speakers

I am trying to replace a 2 channel speaker with another 1 channel speaker. To do so, I connected every wire (+ & -) to a resistor, then connected both -ves and +ves together (I read how to do it somewhere). I tried doing this on a breadboard first, and it worked well, the sound and volume were good.  But then when I connected the resistors directly to the wires (without the help of the breadboard), the volume somehow decreases, even though the rest of the circuit did not change. The volume is the same as when I connect only 1 channel to the speaker. I do not know why this is happening and would really appreciate some help. 
I tried coiling the resistor around the wire and removing the coils but no changes happened. I tried both channels separately and they both work, so that rules out any fault with the connections or wires. The circuit is currently connected on the breadboard, just the resistors are directly connected to the wires so there is no doubt that this is the problem. 
 This is my first time playing around with hardware, so excuse any possible stupidity :) Thanks in advance!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJkZfw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

 
The circuit on the breadboard, note that the volume is high, and the quality of the sound is perfect (working as expected) (white is +ve and black is -ve): 
[![Circuit on breadboard][1]][1]

Connecting the resistors with the wires using electrical tape and without changing the circuit (volume decreases for some reason, becomes like when connecting only one channel): 
[![Connecting the resistors with the wires using electrical tape and without changing the circuit][2]][2]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than words. You can add one in **using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar**. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and **Save and Insert** on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid. There are symbols for resistors and loudspeakers.

Comment: I'm sorry about that :) It is a very simple circuit though, theoretically it should work. When I connected the circuit on the breadboard, it worked perfectly. But then when I connected the resistors to the wires from the channels with electrical tape, the volume decreases. The rest of the circuit is exactly the same, so I am wondering if there is a "correct" way to connect resistors to wires, or if I am missing something bigger.

Comment: There is no theory which indicates it should work, because you don't say which device, module, or chip you are using and if it works in a way that won't allow you to connect the outputs together with resistors. Besides if your speakers are typical 8 ohm devices, any amount of resistance in series will make it less loud, and adding 44 ohms in series with 8 ohms is a lot.

Comment: Show us a couple of pics of what you've actuality built, both with and without the breadboard.

Comment: Please expand your schematic to include the speakers, their impedance and your amplifier.

Comment: @Justme I get that 22 Ohm resistor is too much (it should just be 5), but that still doesn't explain why it works on the breadboard (1st pic) but not in the second. That is what I'm trying to figure out...

Comment: @brhans I posted the pics, I hope they are clear enough. The only diff b/w the 2 pics is that I connected the resistors to the wires using electrical tape, and idky the volume decreases

Comment: In your 1st pic, each resistor has both of its legs in the same row of the breadboard. So the breadboard is bypassing the resistors. You'll find that if you take that circuit and remove the resistors from the breadboard it'll carry on working just as it was before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your circuit is built wrong. The resistors in the first picture are all shorted out by the breadboard. So it is a different circuit from your second picture where the current actually flows via the resistors.

Comment: had to look up why it was shorted out and I finally get it.. total noob mistake lol.. thnk u